# What's the purpose of using letter 'x' or 'X' as a suffix in brand names?

Tags: suffixes, brands

What's the purpose of using letter 'x' or 'X' as a suffix in brand names?

Some examples:

- SpaceX
- HubX
- TEDx

Comment: e**X**tended. But for Microsoft DirectX, the X stands as a wildcard for  Direct3D, DirectDraw, DirectMusic, DirectPlay, DirectSound.

Comment: Some people feel it's seXy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Most such uses come from using *x* as a placeholder - a variable name. *Brand X* means any (other) brand - substitute whatever for *X*.

   Why has *x*, in particular, been used as a placeholder? My guess is that it is because it has had (and still has) so few other immediate associations.  For a placeholder name that is entirely non-committal about the kind of replacements possible, you want a name that has no, or few, associations.

   Another way of putting this is that if a name has few or no other meanings then there is little chance of variable "name capture", that is, ambiguity.  If a name means something else then you have to point out specially that you are using it here as a placeholder.  If it has no other meaning then you do not need to do that.

   Because this has been done lots with *x* (and a few other names) in particular, ***x* has become the poster-child placeholder**.
2. Other uses come from some word pronounced with the sound "*ex*", especially *extra*.  In such cases the association is with something that is special (improved, super,...) or has extra features.

Comment: Brandnames are usually striving to sound impressive. Why would anybody think that inserting a mere placeholder makes a name impressive?

Comment: @jsw29: *"Brand X"* is not intended as the name for an actual brand. The whole thing is a place holder, like *"Name"* instead of an actual name. *"Brand X"* was used in advertisements for *particular* (real) brands, contrasting them with an arbitrary hypothetical brand, *"Brand X"*.